# How can I compile two version of my code in IAR Embbedded Workbench

Tags: c, iar

I have two version of code and I need to switch them as work need to compile each one while keeping two version on an IAR project. I find something like "compile switch" but I don't know how is it doing. Is there anyone tell me a keyword or an advice that can I search?

Comment: You can have multiple *configurations* in project, or multiple projects in *workspace*.

Comment: Why can't you do this with a version control system?

Comment: Does SVN has such a specific feature, or do you suggest that choose which version and compile it? I actually need something like preprocessor command.

Comment: In addition, I mean code versions have different feature not revised version of each one of them,.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C preprocessor #define feature to toggle between code versions and use IAR EWARM project's **Defined Symbols feature** to enable a list of #defines in a specific header file (for example: defines.h) that will be included in all C files.

***defines.h***

```
#if defined(PROD_VERSION)

    #define SOFTWARE_VERSION_PRODUCT ("1.0-release")
    //...whetever specific #defines meant for the release version, for example...
    //#define ENABLE_RF_STUB
    #define USE_SERIAL_CTS_RTS

#elif defined(TEST_VERSION)

    #define SOFTWARE_VERSION_PRODUCT ("1.0-test")
    //...whetever specific #defines meant for the test version, for example...
    #define ENABLE_RF_STUB
    #define USE_SERIAL_CTS_RTS

#elif defined(DEBUG_VERSION)

    #define SOFTWARE_VERSION_PRODUCT ("1.0-debug")
    //...whetever specific #defines meant for the debug version, for example...
    #define ENABLE_RF_STUB
    //#define USE_SERIAL_CTS_RTS

#endif
```

in ***rf.c***

```
#include "defines.h"

void rfInit(void)
{
#ifndef ENABLE_RF_STUB
    //init RF here
#endif
}
```

In ***serial.c***

```
#include "defines.h"

CPU_BOOLEAN isCtsRts()
{
#ifdef USE_SERIAL_CTS_RTS
    return HAL_SERIAL.isCtsRts();
#else
    return DEF_TRUE; //bypass CtsRts check
#endif
}
```

In **your project option > C/C++ Compiler > Preprocessor > Defined symbols**: add *PROD_VERSION* if you want the release version, or add *TEST_VERSION* if you want the test version or add *DEBUG_VERSION* if you want the debug version.

You can only choose one of the three configurations above only as IAR will only compile one version via the project compilation. Unless you can create a batch build script to allow building all the three versions under different output files created with three different project setups.

Answer (score 0):

IAR has a configuration in toolbar **Project > Edit_Configuration** 
It makes you set version "switches" via set these tool and it is possible to set preprocessor command for each setup.